# JMS Transaction Context vs JPA Transaction Context

Tags: jpa, jms, ejb

I am trying to rollback an MDB message but I dont want the JPA transaction to be rolled back. At the same time, I don't want to run database updates off a new transaction context using TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW to minimize connection resource usage.

using mdb.setRollbackOnly() rolls back both the transaction context and mdb message.

Comment: actually I don't have an answer (because I am not much familiar with MDB), but 2 tips : 1- If the MDB throws application exception , the db transaction is not rolled back automatically, it only does when you call ejbContext.setRollBackOnly() or a system exception is thrown ... can this help in your case to throw an exception instead of calling setRollBackonly ... 2- check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929986/jms-transaction-context-vs-jpa-transaction-context .... I think it describes a solution to the inverse case using BMT , might it help in your case